# windows command doesn't work if pasted

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I cannot find an explanation for this phenomenon (same command gives an error and succeeds as well):

[image]

The only difference between the two lines is that

- the first was **pasted** from a website but then **edited manually** to fit my custom path (the part between the "")
- the second was **typed manually** entirely

I reproduced this each time: when running the pasted command I get an error, when I run the manually typed one, it succeeds.

I checked and triple checked for extra characters (empty trailing spaces). I also copied them in notepad++ and checked "show all characters" but nothing appeard. When I copy-pasted them back from notepad++, they both worked.

This thing also happens when trying to run a shortcut (which runs the command) created on the desktop (this is where it all started - the pasted command failed inexplicably).

Any idea?

**Note:** running on Windows7 x64 and the task scheduled is (as the name suggests) a disable of UAC for Visual Studio 2013 created as described [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-annoying-uac-prompts-how-to-create-a-user-account-control-whitelist-windows/).

Comment: Can you paste the command that failed here? It could be due to some hidden unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

got it!! it's the " " - the pasted ones are not recognized (although in cmd they look the same as the typed ones). Apparently they are a different character (?)

I tryied copying from the website directly into notepad++ and they don't look the same:

[image]